# Accessing Python intepreter's data stack through sys.set_trace

Tags: python, interpreter, cpython

I am using `sys.set_trace(..)` to perform a bytecodes analysis on python code.
More specifically, I set a tracer function to be triggered every time a bytecode gets executed.

For my analysis I need to get the object on which the bytecode with opcode `"STORE_ATTR"` is going to store a value. 
E.g. I have this bytecode:

```
Instruction(opname='STORE_ATTR', opcode=95, arg=9, argval='pos', argrepr='pos', offset=188, starts_line=None, is_jump_target=False)
```

Upon seeing this, the interpreter will try to pop the top element from the data-stack in order to store a value in it.
Is there a way for me to access that object as well? Is there an API like a ***TOP()*** function that I can call from within the tracer and get the top value of the stack of the frame that is being currently executed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, such information is not accessible through Python, but you can do that with the C API. Another issue here is that this is highly dependent on the Python version you have. The following holds for `Python 3.8.5`, but with small modifications can work for other versions too.

The equivalent [`PyEval_SetTrace`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/c-api/init.html#c.PyEval_SetTrace) has access to the [`f_stacktop`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Include/frameobject.h#L27) field of `PyFrameObject` class. This field is used by [`TOP()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Python/ceval.c#L952) at `ceval.c`.

You can also verify that `f_stacktop` is not exposed to the Python `frame` class [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.5/Objects/frameobject.c#L14).

Here you can see a code sample that gets access to the TOS of the current frame:

```cpp
int tracefunc(PyObject *obj, PyFrameObject *frame, int what, PyObject *arg) {
    [...]
    PyObject **stack_pointer = frame->f_stacktop;
    PyObject *tos = stack_pointer[-1];
    [...]
}
```

Comment: Note that `f_stacktop` is usually set to `NULL` - trace functions happen to be one of the very few situations where `f_stacktop` has a usable value, and even then, only when tracing `'line'` or `'opcode'` events, and only the top stack frame will have a usable `f_stacktop`.